# Where does the emqtt stores data

Tags: emq

In Emqtt where does it stores all the information regarding the client subscription, nodes details, statistics, etc. As per some article I found that it'll be stored in data/mnesia folder for each node. Is is correct?? if correct then how it'll store.

Answer (score 0):

The persistent data like retain messages are stored in data/mnesia folder, but the information you mentioned like `subscriptions`, `connections` and `metrics` are stored in the memory only, using either ETS or Mnesia tables.